# не работает .getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

Я хотел сделать `modal zoom` для нескольких изображении но у меня не работает `getElementsByClassName`. но если брать каждого отдельно то скрипт работает(через `getElementById`). Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('myIm');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
elem.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<img class="myIm" src="d1.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img class="myIm" src="d2.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img class="myIm" src="d3.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close">X</span>
<img class="modal-content" id="img01">
<div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` возвращает массив, поэтому `elem.onclick` работать не будет. Нужно назначать обработчик отдельно для каждого элемента, можно просто циклом:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) elem[i].onclick = ...
```

а можно, например, так:

```
elem.forEach((div) => { div.onclick = ... });
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName возвращает [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), у которой нет метода _forEach_, поэтому итерировать нужно так: `[].forEach.call(items, (div) => { div.onclick = ... });`

Comment: @АлексейУколов, данный метод есть _не везде_, например в хроме он присутствует